# FIFA 12: Ultimate team frustration

Tags: fifa-12

I've been having some problems winning games lately. I still remember the time when I had a really good team that I had built up from the ground with very little money; I used to win 5:0 and I even won against a guy who had 2 informs in his possession. As I got on with my bronze team, things started getting tougher... Now I have GIANT difficulties winning against another guy's starter pack with my premium 90 pace bronze team. After a quartet of bitter 3:0 and 2:2 defeats I got really frustrated...

My question is: Does the ingame level (I'm level 19) affect the people you are getting matched with? I feel like my level is sky-rocketing although I'm not getting better. If so, How can I reset my level to have my own share of "6:0 N00B P4WN!NG"?

As I started playing, I lost 6 games, all 10:0 for my opponent. How did those people, clearly better than me get matched up with me, a noob?

Please tell me what I should do. I'm getting dangerously close to throwing the disc out of the window or putting it into the microwave and watching it burn.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not underestimate the power of;

- player morale
- team chemistry

I have gone through the same before and noticed a couple of midfielders with either poor morale, fitness, or chemistry. Formation tweaks, & fitness/morale cards saved the day.

Answer (score -2):

It's because your players are really good and your experience level is fairly high. If you make a team that isn't 5 stars, then you will play teams that are more your level.

Comment: Dude, i'm afraid you got that a little wrong. To escape the pressure of a good 5-star team i made a totally new one, a bronze one.